# Flask -- Reloading database which was loaded before first request

Tags: mongodb, python-3.x, flask

I have an API run on flask which is connected to MongoDB and it uses this DB for reading only.
I connect to db before first request:

```
@app.before_first_request
def load_dicti():
    c = MongoClient('mongodb://' + app.config['MONGO_DSN'], connect=False)
    db = c.my_name
    app.first, app.second = dictionary_compilation(db.my_base, another_dictionary)
```

However, this mongodb may be updated from time to time. My API doesn't know about it because this db was already loaded before first request.

What's the most efficient way to cope with it? I'd be grateful for explanations and code examples.

Answer (score -1):

I don't quite figure out what you are going to do, but [Application Context](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/appcontext/#app-context) may be best practice. Just like [demo](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/tutorial/dbcon/) in Flask docs, you could do:

```
def get_db():
    """Opens a new database connection if there is none yet for the
    current application context.
    """
    if not hasattr(g, 'db'):
        c = MongoClient('mongodb://' + app.config['MONGO_DSN'], connect=False)
        g.db = c.my_name
    return g.db
```

Then, you could use `get_db()` directly in your view function, mongdb will be conntected once only when there is no `db` attr in `g`.

If your connection is not that stable that you need to change it everytime, you could connect every request or every [session](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/testing/#accessing-and-modifying-sessions).

Comment: I upload the database into api memory before first request.
If I understand your suggestion right then:
a) database is loaded if it has not been uploaded in this session;
b) does it happen before first request in this case?

Comment: what do you mean by `upload`? Is it that you will initialize `app.config['MONGO_DSN']` before first request? in most case, an MongoClient instance is reusable and thread-safe, so its is shared by being created in app context

Comment: I mean that the database is stored in api memory after db = c.my_name which happens after before_first_request decorator
In my case, I need to read it again afterwards so I have to change it

Comment: how about put it in `g` after `db = c.my_name`, like appending line `g.db = db`? then you could get it by `g.db` in other requests, is it what you want?

Comment: I need actually two things:
1) the database must not being uploaded at each request to api;
2) Sometimes I still may have to reload it (probably manually); maybe by means of another api method

How may I do it with g.db?

Comment: now i am confused again, what do `reload` mean then? you might check how you have to do in such way? is there any way to avoid what you said `upload` or `reload`? connecting to db should  be as simple as it can, or bugs come here and there